# QT Designer: how to align a button to the right (in resizable form)

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Usign QTDesigner it's not clear to me how to keep a button aligned to the right also when the form is resized..

Button is placed inside a tab widget that is resized correctly.
I try different layout but no one works for me...

Any suggestion ?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Put the button in a horizontal or grid layout, and then put an expanding horizontal spacer on the left-hand side of the button (so it pushes it to the right):

[image]